# How to feed in a time-series into pyunicorn.timeseries.surrogates?

Tags: python

I struggle to find out how to feed a time-series that consists of a one-column .txt file  into pyunicorn’s `timeseries.surrogates`. My one-column .txt file contains many numerical datapoints that constitute the time-series.

Pyunicorn offers several examples how to apply its surrogate methods in this link: [http://www.pik-potsdam.de/~donges/pyunicorn/api/timeseries/surrogates.html](http://www.pik-potsdam.de/%7Edonges/pyunicorn/api/timeseries/surrogates.html)

Paradigmatically, the last surrogate option in the link above, namely for `white_noise_surrogates(original_data)`, Pyunicorn offers the following explanatory code.

```
ts = Surrogates.SmallTestData().original_data
surrogates = Surrogates.SmallTestData().white_noise_surrogates(ts)
```

Clearly, the example data `SmallTestData()` is part of pyunicorn. But how would I have to enter my data, that is, `Data_2`, into the code above? The code

`surrogates = Surrogates.white_noise_surrogates(Data_2)` returns the message

```
TypeError: Surrogates.correlated_noise_surrogates() missing 1 required positional argument: 'original_data'
```

Trying the code in another try

```
TS = Surrogates.Data_2().original_data
Surrogate = Surrogates.correlated_noise_surrogates(TS)
```

returns into the message

```
AttributeError: type object 'Surrogates' has no attribute 'Data_2'
```

I assume that there is a simple solution, but I cannot figure it out. Here is an overview of my code:

```
from pyunicorn.timeseries import Surrogates
import pyunicorn as pn
Data_2 = np.loadtxt("/path-to-data.txt")
   
# Surrogate time-series
TS = Surrogates.Data_2().original_data
Surrogate = Surrogates.correlated_noise_surrogates(TS)
```

Does anyone understand how to properly feed or insert a time-series into pyunicorn’s `timeseries.surrogates` options?

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the class `Surrogates` with your data

```py
TS = Surrogates(original_data=Data_2)     
my_surr = TS.correlated_noise_surrogates(Data_2)
```